# How can client send a request and receive multiple responses?

Tags: http, go, distributed, coordinate-systems

I am trying to send a request from client machine to the server A, and receive response from Server A, B, and C. Once A received the request from the Client, it forwards it to Server B, and C. So, after all servers learned about client request, every server will process the request and then respond to the client. In this case, the client will receive many responses. My question is how to send one request for one server and receive many responses for single request. I know that http is not working in this scenario. Is there any suggestions? 
Note: I am using Golang.
Thanks.

Comment: For security purpose, I want every server to reply directly to the client after they learned the request from Server A.

Comment: @SalemAlqahtani this is not possible with any normal set-up we think about where connection is initiated by client. Client holds connection only with server A so, it can receive response only from A. But, if client is capable of receiving incoming connections. server B and server C can establish connections to client and send their responses. But, then you have to track request with unique request identifier. It is quite convoluted. Can you elaborate your use-case in more detail?

Comment: The use case for this example is PBFT, Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerant. Client sends it's request to the primary server, then primary server forwards the request for all other servers(replica). Then if all servers agreed. Every server will send its agreement back to the client. The reason is preventing primary of being malicious.

Comment: @SalemAlqahtani here who is client becomes important. If it is an internal service depending on distributed consensus or, external client depending on consensus from service. If your client is using golang, if you can start listening on a port dedicated for receiving responses. Here you can use grpc to communicate efficiently. But, each server would have to connect to client individually.